# Is there a way in markdown to override default mathjax renderer?

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter, mathjax, nbconvert

I'm writing a slide using jupyter/markdown/mathjax/nbconvert.

Turns out that the default mathjax renders poorly:

[image]

The svg renderer however functions properly:

[image]

Unfortunately this renderer is lost everytime I refresh the webpage.

Is there a way to override this in jupyter/markdown/mathjax/nbconvert?

Comment: Is it a [latex] question? :)

Comment: mathjax use latex as backend language, so I assume yes :)

Comment: ever solved this?