# change mathjax renderer in R notebooks (with "self_contained: false")

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, mathjax, rnotebook

I am creating R notebooks that contain equations. I am using RStudio 1.2.5033 on Windows 10, R 3.5.1, and rmarkdown 2.1. When my R notebooks are rendered as HTML, MathJax (v2.7.2) uses the "HTML-CSS" output processor to render the equations. But I think that the output from the "CommonHTML" output processor looks better. So I want to include a directive, in my R notebooks, that forces MathJax to use the CommonHTML output processor. How may I do this?

If I were rendering an ordinary R Markdown document with output format `html_document`, I could solve the problem via the `mathjax` option in my YAML header. For example, when the following file is rendered to HTML, MathJax will use the CommonHTML output processor:

```
---
title: "Trouble with MathJax"
output: 
  html_document:
    mathjax: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML.js"
    self_contained: false    
---

\begin{equation}
  R_3 = \alpha
\end{equation}
```

But this solution doesn't work well when I change the `output` format from `html_document` to `html_notebook`. In that case, I get output that looks like this:
[image: screenshot showing problem with html_notebook rendering]

The equation is rendered with CommonHTML, but there is a lot of cruft at the top of the page (note the four bullet points), and the default R Notebook CSS doesn't seem to be implemented.

The problem seems to be general to rendering R notebooks with `self_contained: FALSE`, as suggested in [R notebooks don't render properly when "self_contained" is FALSE because the "files" directory is deleted after rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153998/r-notebooks-dont-render-properly-when-self-contained-is-false-because-the-fi). But I can't see a good workaround for that problem.

#### Dead Ends

The [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/hub.html) seems to indicate that I can specify the output processor by adding the `jax` array in a call to `MathJax.Hub.Config()`. But when I've done that, my equations are still displayed via the HTML-CSS output processor. Here is a minimal example of an R Markdown document that exhibits the problem:

```
---
title: 'Trouble with MathJax'
output: html_notebook
---

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML"],
  });
</script>

\begin{equation}
  R_3 = \alpha
\end{equation}
```

The call to `MathJax.Hub.Config()` seems to do nothing here. In both Chrome and Edge, the equation is rendered via HTML-CSS, not CommonHTML. How can I change the rendering to Common HTML?

#### Related Posts

- One year-old post, [Is there a way in markdown to override default mathjax renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54719132/697473), is about Jupyter notebooks, but it's relevant. It hasn't received an answer.
- Adapting the script in [this post from the MathJax Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/eZwHw3dgZEo/1Fu2yp1EbUsJ) –– mainly by changing "HTML-CSS" to "CommonHTML" –– doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to omit the `self_contained` line in the YAML header or, equivalently, to set `self_contained` to `true`. Here is a minimal example of an R notebook for which the user has chosen the mathjax renderer:

```
---
title: "Self-contained notebook with non-default Mathjax config"
output:
  html_notebook:
    mathjax: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML.js"
---

$R_3 = 2$.
```

When the file is rendered to HTML, the equation is displayed with CommonHTML, not with HTML-CSS. And the Mathjax script is contained within the "nb.html" file that is produced.

I was surprised that this works, because the documentation for `rmarkdown::html_document()` says that "even for self contained documents MathJax is still loaded externally (this is necessary because of its size)." But [Section 3.1.8 of the R Markdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html) indicates that the restriction applies only when Mathjax is loaded from a local file. So perhaps it shouldn't be a surprise.

Side note: the default Mathjax configuration used by the rmarkdown package is given by `rmarkdown:::mathjax_config()`. As of rmarkdown v2.1, the function returns "MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML".